# How to remove unwanted characters from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Guys i need to remove 138;# and #140;# from a string.  I need a function that will work regardless of the number prepending the ;#

The original string is :-

```
138;#RM Bridge;#140;#Maconomy
```

Basically i want `"RM Bridge, Maconomy"` so i can split into an array.

Answer (score 7):

```
string = string.replace(/([0-9]+)?;#/g, '');
```

But keep in mind that you'll get `RM BridgeMaconomy` instead of `RM Bridge, Maconomy`, because there is no `,` in your string.